# Differentiability for the uniform limit of a uniformly bounded sequence of functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let a sequence $\{f_n\}\subset C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f\in C(\mathbb R)$ such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly and $f_n, f'_n$ are uniformly bounded.

Question : is $f \in C^1(\mathbb R)$ ?

Comment: In attempting to apply Ascoli-Arzela, equicontinuity is important.  The result is false on compact intervals, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2+{1 \over n}}$. We have $f_n \to | \cdot |$ uniformly, and all derivatives are bounded (by 1), but the limit is not $C^1$.

Jonas has pointed out a flaw in my example. I think the following is a fix.

Let $f_n(x) = \arctan \sqrt{x^2+{1 \over n}}$, then $f_n \to \arctan \circ (| \cdot |)$ uniformly, and all quantities are bounded.

Comment: Seb also asks for uniform boundedness of $\{f_n\}$.  However, that is easily fixed.  The result is already false on compact intervals.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Thanks for catching that. Let me see if I have sufficient caffeine to effect a quick fix.

Comment: Still working on my coffee.  But, how about multiplying by $e^{-x^2}$?  Edit: Or that.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Thanks for the suggestion. $\arctan$ is usually the first out of my bag :-).

Comment: My notation for the limit function looks like some odd emoticon.

Comment: My favorite emoticon is $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$

Comment: @JonasMeyer: :-).

Comment: Copper's example seem to work! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take $f(x) =  \begin{cases} |x|, &|x|<1 \\ 
1, &|x| \geq 1 \end{cases} $ and $f_n$ as its smooth approximation